# How to add flowtype for functions that take parameters and also use "arguments" internally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

The following code is from an OSS library (for VDOM). I'm trying to add flowtype to `h` function that generates a virtual DOM node. But Notice that the function internally uses `arguments`? It also takes two inputs. Wondering how to type annotate this.

1. The 1st argument is either a string or a function.
2. The 2nd argument is an object w/ lots of key-value
3. It uses arguments internally because function can take N number of parameters.

   a. So the function must have at least 2 parameters (but can have N number of parameters).

   b. And starting from 3rd parameter, these params must be of type `Array` or `string`.

So you can call this:

1. `h("b", {...})` or
2. `h(()=>{}, {...}, [])` or
3. `h(()=>{}, {...}, [], [], []..)`
4. `h(()=>{}, {...}, [], "string", "string2")`

   ```
   var i
   var stack = []

   export function h(tag, props) {
   var node
   var children = []

   for (i = arguments.length; i-- > 2; ) {
    stack.push(arguments[i])
   }

   while (stack.length) {
    if (Array.isArray((node = stack.pop()))) {
      for (i = node.length; i--; ) {
        stack.push(node[i])
       }
      } else if (node != null && node !== true && node !== false) {
       children.push(typeof node === "number" ? (node = node + "") : node)
     }
   }

    return typeof tag === "string" ? {
            tag: tag,
            props: props || {},
            children: children
          }
          : tag(props, children)
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need to do is create a [`libdef`](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs) for the library you're using and put it in the `flow-typed` folder in the root of your project.
Or you can also submit it to the [`flow-typed` repository](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed).

Making a `libdef` isn't that hard. You just make a file `library-name.js` with the following content and declare all the function types inside of it:

```js
declare module 'my-third-party-library' {
  declare type arg1Type = string | () => any;
  declare type arg2Type = {
    [key: string]: any,
  };
  declare type restArgsType = Array<Array<any> | string>;

  declare class className {
    h(arg1: arg1Type, arg2: arg2Type, ...restArgs: restArgsType): void;
  }

  declare var exports: className;
}
```

**Original Answer:**

> I think you can just specify the types of the arguments of the
>   function like this:
>
> ```js
> type arg1Type = string | () => any;
> type arg2Type = {
>   [key: string]: any,
> }
> type restArgsType = Array<Array<any> | string>
> function h(arg1: arg1Type, arg2: arg2Type, ...restArgs: restArgsType){}
> ```
>
> Afterwards you can just use the function like:
>
> ```js
> h('b', obj);
> h(func, obj, []);
> h(func, obj, [], []);
> h(func, obj, [], [], []);
> h(func, obj, [], 'string', 'string2')
> ```
>
> As you can see on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCGATgOYCMAKjvgLxgDO6RAlgHYlgA+YAFAJRgaAPkKtMAbgzVCpAExU8gsAG9UYMAG0A1rkwAuBkzYkAugYJiANKgC+UxUVyMAgqXoLaYV0QKYAPN6+fhaYItyMLOxCqFAArqwAxujMcKxgABY8xOTmpJTUljIksrnFHoUAdFWOLm4GNeiuJO7UfMp2qAmpjGBwAEYAVkqq6tjEBAC2ZAYA5GM+UzPWNpJdrD1xiUr8wmAz6E7oM5KomTN9S72DfJKZmwmF-QOFGiY3pzz3j4MvJr-vd3iDyuz00fzB-1unyB31Br0KMwixkuiKM7FkMz4QA)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the signature of the `h` function itself. Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: Correct. I'm contributing flowtype to it.

Comment: The best way is to make a libdef, like it's done in the one's provided by `flow-typed`.

Comment: @RajaRao I changed my answer with the provided context you told here in the comments 

Comment: Thanks, but why is h function inside a class? declare class className {
    h(arg1: arg1Type, arg2: arg2Type, ...restArgs: restArgsType): void;
  }

Comment: @RajaRao It doesn't need to be inside a class, the module can just export the function itself if you want. It's just more 'logical' to have it in a class if it's from a third-party library I think?